# Adding a custom WooCommerce payment gateway connection

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Our payment gateway and CRM and not supported by WooCommerce by default as a plugin, so I need to add custom code that sends data to our CRM and payment gateway whenever a customer places an order, then reject or accept the order depending on the payment gateway API response.

Where and how in the Woo code should I be intercepting the order submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `woocommerce_checkout_process` action hook where the billing provider's API response, should return an error notice to reject and stop the checkout process…

This hook is located in [`WC_Checkout` `process_checkout()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#940-995) and it's before the order creation. The data is accessible through `$_POST` or through `$posted_data = WC()->checkout->get_posted_data();` `WC_Checkout` method.

Or `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` action hook where the order is already created (meaning that the order data is accessible through 3 arguments: `$order_id`, `$posted_data` and `$order`) but **before payment**… To stop the process the billing provider's API response should: `throw new Exception()`…

> So anyway the solution is one of the `WC_Checkout` available hooks…